# Page not loading with ip address

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, webserver

I have a `webserver` running `apache and tomcat as apache as front end`. The thing is when I give the url of domain the page is loading. but when I give ip in the address bar it is not loading. the follwoing is my configuration in apache.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.98:80>
   JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/workers.properties
   JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
   JkLogLevel info
   JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
   JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
   JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
   JkMount /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Why it is not loading when I give `192.168.1.98` in browser?
it is giving a blank page. 
Help

Comment: if I'm giving ip -> hostname in windows host file, site is loading but I want this site to load when accessing through IP address. Any idea?

Comment: Ok. I think I have found the real cause. Even 192.168.1.98:8080 is not working. How to configure tomcat to serve the request  from IP?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the ip for some domain and put this ip for this domain in the /etc/hosts the problem is still the same? I never create a virtualhost using a ip, only using some domain name. Probably you have some defalt rule for your server in a different place in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I dont have any ip configured anywhere. This is fresh system. /etc/hosts is as follows.


`[root@test1 html]# cat /etc/hosts
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.0.1       test1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
192.168.1.15    test1.lukup.internal
192.168.1.98 www.lukup.com`